# $\sin(\pi - a) = \sin (a)$. How/why?

Tags: trigonometry

Can someone please explain how and why $\sin(\pi - a) = \sin (a)$? The handout from class doesn't really explain it. I tried asking the teach but there's a bit of a language barrier and I'm not getting how he's explaining it.

Comment: What's in the handout?

Comment: What's your definition of $\sin$? Is it in terms of triangles or complex exponentials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First,  use the fact that $\sin$ is an odd function, so $\sin (\pi -a)=-\sin (a-\pi)$.  Now,  shifting a sine or cosine function by half a period flips the sign again (You can look at the graph to see the reason why), so $\sin (a-\pi)=-\sin (a)$.  Combining the two together, the double negatives cancel and we get the desired equality

Comment: I think if you're going to mention 'shifting by half a period flips the sign' it isn't too much of a leap to do the whole question by flipping and shifting along by pi. This may also make it more clear what's going on for the OP.

Comment: Ok I see. Reading that, and thinking of it like that makes a lot of other things make more sense now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at it in terms of the unit circle, $\sin(a)$ represents the $y$-value when you travel counterclockwise $a$ radians, starting from the point $(1,0)$.  $\sin(\pi-a)$ then would represent you starting halfway around ($\pi$ radians) the unit circle, at the point $(-1,0)$, and then going $a$ radians *clockwise*, since it is negative.  If you look at those two points at any angle $a$, you see that one is essentially just a reflection across the $y$-axis of the other, and so while the $x$-value is not the same (negative), the $y$-value will still be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the added detail.

Comment: Omg I love you, I think I finally understand the transformation/phase shifts for moving left and right on the x-axis are opposite signed.